# Check if a string contains an array of strings

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to find out if any of the words in the array `keywords`:

```
keywords = Array['hello', 'hi', 'home']
```

appear in `split`:

```
split = work.split(' ')
```

and for each `keyword` that appears in `split`, do something.

I have this code:

```
for keywords in splitDescription
  score += 2
end
```

The code just gives me 2+ for each word in `split`, but I only want 2+ for each `keywords` appearing in `split`.

Comment: A few things about writing idiomatic Ruby: Use `x = [1, 2, 3]`, not `x = Array[1, 2, 3]` (the `Array` is redundant here) for creating arrays, and use `keywords.each do |keyword|` instead of `for keyword in keywords`.

Comment: What is `work`? What do you mean that it gives you 2+?

Comment: "work" is storing a string and by 2+ i mean the score increments by 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use set intersection on arrays (`Array#&`):

```
(splitDescription & keywords).each do |found_keyword|
  # something
end
```

---

If you know there might be some words repeating and you want to iterate over each occurrence:

```
splitDescription.select { |word| keywords.include?(word) }.each do |word|
  # something
end
```